# sqlite compile option with SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

Tags: sqlite, makefile, configure

I get syntax error with sqlite3:

> delete from table_x where 1=1 limit 10;

Looks like I am missing this compilation option (http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html)
`SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1`

But I am not sure how to compile with this option on linux:

I did the following, but doesn't seem to work.

```
./configure SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1;
make clean;
make
```

I also tried this, but get make option error.

```
./configure SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1;
make clean;
make -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1 // nope
make SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1 // nope
```

What is the correct way to add a compile option to sqlite make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1'
./configure
make clean
make
```

The export sets the environment variable CFLAGS which is passed along to the C compiler as defines. You can specify more than one define within the quotes if you wish (multiple compile options) they just need to be separated by spaces.

Comment: Yes, I added simple print statements to see that I actually get to the ifdef SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT sections in sqlite3.c and see the prints. I'm wondering if my delete statement is wrong? I'm basically trying to remove the first 10 rows from the table to save space.

Comment: For sqlite3, it looks like I need the semicolon to separate statements. Without it, the prompt is a line continuation, in cmd line.

Comment: I have sqlite3 handy on a system here. I ran it and it did accept the limit command and there was no error. Your create table failed though. At least on my sqlite3 it had to be changed slightly to this `create table table_x(val_int int, val_obj text, ts DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` notice how I had to use `datetime` instead of `timestamp`.

Comment: sqlite-autoconf-3080403
3.8.5

Comment: Oh, what version of sqlite3 are you using? Maybe I can try newer version.

Comment: I just tried downloading and compiling 3.8.6 (http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080600.tar.gz) with SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT and am hitting the same error with the sql delete limit statement (delete from table_x where 1=1 limit 10;) on a darwin linux.

Comment: My guess is there is a compiling problem in your environment (Darwin). It may compile but doesn't run properly. This can happen. I can be contacted offline at mpetch@capp-sysware.com . If you could send me a copy of the config.log and config.h file that were generated I may be able to help further.

Comment: In sqlite3.c, it looks like the limit function doesn't get called anywhere (sqlite3LimitWhere)? Instead, it looks like codeTriggerProgram calls sqlite3DeleteFrom instead. Not sure how sqlite3 can process sqlite3LimitWhere then. So is (delete from table_x where 1=1 limit 10;) an invalid statement?

Comment: It isn't invalid here on my Sqlite3. It works as expected. No errors and deletes properly. I used a table just like yours and populated it with fake data and was able to remove them with a limit

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in configure script which makes it failed to pass DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT to lemon parser generator in Makefile when generating parser.c:

generated Makefile:

```
1063 parse.c: $(TOP)/src/parse.y lemon$(BEXE)
1064     cp $(TOP)/src/parse.y .
1065     ./lemon$(BEXE) $(OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS) $(OPTS) -S parse.y
```

original configure script:

```
11603 #########
11604 # See whether we should enable JSON1
11605 # Check whether --enable-json1 was given.
11606 if test "${enable_json1+set}" = set; then :
11607   enableval=$enable_json1;
11608 fi
11609
11610 if test "${enable_json1}" = "yes" -o "${enable_all}" = "yes" ; then
11611   OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS="${OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS} -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1"
11612 fi
```

You can fix it by making replacement following:

modified configure script:

```
11614 #########
11615 # See whether we should enable the LIMIT clause on UPDATE and DELETE
11616 # statements.
11617 # Check whether --enable-update-limit was given.
11618 if test "${enable_update_limit+set}" = set; then :
11619   enableval=$enable_update_limit;enable_udlimit=yes
11620 else
11621   enable_udlimit=no
11622 fi
11623
11624 if test "${enable_udlimit}" = "yes" ; then
11625   OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS="${OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS} -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT"
11626 fi
```

then run:

```
./configure --enable-update-limit
make clean
make sqlite3
```